# List all grantable roles in my GCP environment

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, roles, google-iam

I'm a newbie and was looking for some help.

How do I list all grantable roles within my GCP environment at the organization level?
I am using...
`gcloud iam list-grantable-roles`
but everywhere I read it says I must specify the resource I want to check. I want it to check all resources.

Thank you for help!

Comment: I am trying to analyze the current roles/permissions in the current GCP projects and consolidate the different roles/permissions in use today. There are many projects. Is there a way to check all of them?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Your question is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles can be used in two ways. Applied to identities and applied to resources. When applied to resources (your example) you must specify the resource because resources only support a subset of all possible roles. For example, it makes no sense to apply a Compute Engine role to a Cloud Storage object.

To list all possible roles for an organization:

```
gcloud iam roles list --organization ORG_ID
```

Comment: I am trying to analyze the current roles/permissions in the current GCP projects and consolidate the different roles/permissions in use today. There are many projects. Is there a way to check all of them?

Comment: @bleyto - I answered the question you asked. Create a new question with details: What do you mean by current roles? Do you mean custom roles or do you mean roles that are in current use?

Comment: Yes you answered my question and thank you for that. I created a new question this morning. I appreciate your help thought maybe a comment would suffice. Also i mean roles in current use

Comment: @bleyto - accept the answer so that it does not stay **open** forever.